# props.children rendering with parent container on each child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a side menu that takes in children and renders them. The side menu does render the children but each child is wrapped in all the render output of the side menu. I can't find a way to stop this from happening.

I have tried without using material UI with styles but the same thing happens.

This is how it outputs using basic rendering, using `return <div>{this.props.children}</div>` or the code below.

[Inspector output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OdS0.png)

The code:

main page

```
<SideMenu>
    <Tab id="Search" header="Search" icon={<SearchIcon />}>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <Foo />
    </Tab>
    <Tab  id="home" header="Home" icon={<SearchIcon />}>
        <h1>Some text again</h1>
        <Foo />
        <Bar />
    </Tab>
</SideMenu>
```

sideMenu

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import {
  withStyles
} from "@material-ui/core";

import styles from "./styles";

class SideMenu extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    children: PropTypes.any,
    // events
  };

  state = {

  }

  renderChildren(children) {
    return React.Children.map(children, p =>
      React.cloneElement(p, {})
    )
  }

  render() {
    const { children, classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.sideMenuRoot}>
        <div className={classes.sideMenuTabPane}>
        </div>

        <div className={classes.sideMenuContent}>
          {this.renderChildren(children)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(SideMenu);
```

tab

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Tab extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {};

  state = {};

  render() {
    return null
  }
}

export default Tab;
```

Comment: I guess your Tab component should render first along with all the props such as text/icon or any other callbacks. After this you can simply just call props.children inside your sideMenu component. It will not create any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that you need to do all the renderChildren function. Did something like this before should only need to pass {children}.

Main Page:

```
<SideMenu>
    <Tab id="Search" header="Search" icon={<SearchIcon />} text="Some Text" />
    <Tab  id="home" header="Home" icon={<SearchIcon />} text="Some Text" />
</SideMenu>
```

Sidemenu:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import {
  withStyles
} from "@material-ui/core";

import styles from "./styles";

class SideMenu extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    children: PropTypes.any,
    // events
  };

  state = {

  }

  render() {
    const { children, classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.sideMenuRoot}>
        <div className={classes.sideMenuTabPane}>
        </div>

        <div className={classes.sideMenuContent}>
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(SideMenu);
```

Tab:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Tab extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {};

  state = {};

  render() {
    const { text } = this.props;
    return (
      <h1>{text}</h1>
    )
  }
}

export default Tab;
```

Comment: I'm also trying to pass other children into each tab, not just text unfortunetly.

Comment: @Kennyist What kind of things? Will all the Tabs be using them? Could build on the Tab component you have and pass information to them, could solve your problem.